# allocating zero-copy struct on integrated GPU

Tags: cuda

I wonder what is the best way to allocate a struct that is accessible by both the host and the device. Take the following struct as example:

```
struct Buff {
    int * index; 
    Chunk * chunks;
}
```

where Chunk is a simple struct of arrays:

```
struct Chunk {
    int sas[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int das[CHUNK_SIZE];
};
```

Right now I achieve this by first allocating zero-copy memory for the struct, and then for the struct members, as the following:

```
Buff * my_buff;

// Allocate zero-copy memory for the struct (as the container)
checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc(&my_buff, sizeof(Buff), cudaHostAllocMapped));

// Allocate zero-copy memory for index
checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc(&my_buff->index, sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocMapped));

// Allocate zero-copy memory for the array of chunks
checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc(&my_buff->chunks, sizeof(Chunk) * NUM_CHUNKS, cudaHostAllocMapped));
```

However, I would like to know if there is a more efficient way for this, something like the way deep copy is handled automatically in Unified Memory.

Comment: I believe your method is best.  I'm assuming you are working on a Tegra TK1 or TX1.  In that case, what you generally want to do for best performance is to *avoid* any memory-to-memory copying at all.  Zero-copy should achieve that.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks! Yes, actually, I work with both. As a follow up question: how many accesses to global memory are needed to read/write my_buff->index? I hope only one.

Comment: I see no point in `index` being a pointer. If  `buff` is already GPU accessible, then what purpose  does it serve?

Comment: It should be only one to read write *that value*.  It is effectively just dereferencing an offset from the `my_buff` pointer.  But, as @talonmies has pointed out, `index` is also a *pointer*.  So it will take one access to read the pointer value, and then one more access if you dereference that pointer.  So in general, these pointer-chasing schemes are not optimal for GPU usage.  The usual advice is to flatten such structures, effectively converting from AoS to SoA methodology.

Comment: @talonmies You are right! but the reason is that cudaHostAlloc takes pointer to pointer as the first argument, so I thought that's the only way!

Comment: you are right! That happened because initially I had just allocated memory for the members and then I needed a pointer. But now that I also allocate for the struct itself, I don't need the index to be pointer any more. Thank you both.

Comment: @user3032459: If you want to write a short answer to your question (its OK to do that), I will happily upvote it to get this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the short answer to my question extracted from the comments above.

It seems that the basic idea of the method is all right, in the sense that first you allocate zero-copy memory for the struct, and then for each of the pointer members.

However, in this case, `index` should not be a pointer because `my_buff` is already GPU accessible and having `index` as a pointer would cost one more global memory access. In general, pointer-chasing schemes are not optimal for GPU usage, and the usual advice is to flatten such structures, effectively converting from AoS to SoA methodology.